# Configuration for cassandra with rac and vnodes in single data center

Tags: cassandra

I was wondering which configuration will be best suited for even distribution of data among nodes.

1. 5 nodes with 3 racs (2 nodes(node 1,node4) on rac1 , 2 nodes on rac2 (node2,node4) , 1 node on rac3 (node3))
   Replication factor 3 and Read / Write on Quorum

In this case I am wondering whether the node3 which is the only node in rac3 will have more data than other nodes since replication strategy suggests that replicas will be but in nodes on different rac.

2. 6 nodes with 3 racs (2 nodes(node 1,node4) on rac1 , 2 nodes on rac2 (node2,node4) , 2 nodes on rac3 (node3, node6)) 
   Replication factor 3 and Read / Write on Quorum

In this case data will be distributed equally among all nodes.

Want to know whether my understanding is correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of 5 nodes across 3 racks, yes, one node will be under greater load/stress.

It's a good idea to scale the cluster in multiples of the rack count to keep the data balanced across nodes. For example, in a 3 rack cluster you should add 3 nodes each time you expand the cluster.

If you choose to use multiple racks the ideal rack count should be ≥ your chosen *replication factor*. This allows Cassandra to store each replica in a separate rack.

In the case of a rack outage the other replicas would be still available.

For example, with RF=3 and 3 racks and queries at `QUORUM`, you can sustain the failure of a single rack. Whereas, with RF=3 and 2 racks at `QUORUM`, there is no guarantee that 2 replicas will still be available in the case of a rack failure.

Racks are for informing Cassandra about fault domains. If your running in your own data center, as the name implies, racks should be assigned based on the rack the node is located in. If you're running in the cloud, the best option is to map racks to AWS *availability zones* (or whatever is equivalent for your provider).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use 6 nodes to make sure you have equal number of nodes in each rack - having equal number of nodes in each rack is a basic requirement when going with multiple racks.

But, do you really need to have multiple racks ? because it makes scaling more difficult when you want to scale up as every time you need take care of the alternate node order and the data distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra, Multiple RACKs provide data continues availability in cassandra cluster for any disastrous situations. Cassandra recommends also the same in prod cluster. your both option is fine. however, you should go odd number of nodes in cassandra cluster.